# Rails and Ruby app is crashed after launch if i use wicked_pdf gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, wicked-pdf

I just started a Rails and Ruby application just 20 days back and i am very new to this application . In this app I need to generate the PDF file from HTML , so i used **Wicked_pdf** and this is working as we expected if I use only rails and Ruby , later i added Rails_admin once install Rails_admin then launch app (**rails s**) for testing and it gives url http:// localhost:3000 . Whenever i run the url in browser then immediately app is closed without giving any error .

[image]

Can any one please guide how to solve this issue .

Thanks